# How to show only specific days react-dates

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker, momentjs, react-dates

I have array of days.

```
const availableDates = ["2019-02-01", "2019-02-04", "2019-02-05", "2019-02-06", "2019-02-07", "2019-02-11", "2019-02-12", "2019-02-13", "2019-02-14", "2019-02-15", "2019-02-19", "2019-02-20", "2019-02-21", "2019-02-22", "2019-02-23", "2019-02-25", "2019-02-26", "2019-02-27", "2019-02-28", "2019-03-01", "2019-03-04", "2019-03-05", "2019-03-06", "2019-03-07", "2019-03-08", "2019-03-09", "2019-03-11", "2019-03-12"]
```

I only want to show the above selected days in the airbnb datepicker and disable the other ones.

```
<SingleDatePicker
    date={moment()}
    onDateChange={date => this.setState({ date })} 
    focused={this.state.focused} 
    onFocusChange={({ focused }) => this.setState({ focused })}
    id="your_unique_id"
    numberOfMonths={1}
    renderCalendarDay={() => availableDates.map(d => moment(d).format(d))}
    className="select-btn selectbtn-picker"
/>
```

How can I do that? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to use the `isDayBlocked` prop of the date picker. The following function will find if a day is contained inside your array, and return `true` if it does not find any :

```
isBlocked = day => {
    const availableDates = ["2019-02-01", "2019-02-04", "2019-02-05", "2019-02-06", "2019-02-07", "2019-02-11", "2019-02-12", "2019-02-13", "2019-02-14", "2019-02-15", "2019-02-19", "2019-02-20", "2019-02-21", "2019-02-22", "2019-02-23", "2019-02-25", "2019-02-26", "2019-02-27", "2019-02-28", "2019-03-01", "2019-03-04", "2019-03-05", "2019-03-06", "2019-03-07", "2019-03-08", "2019-03-09", "2019-03-11", "2019-03-12"]
    return !availableDates.some(date => day.isSame(date), 'day')
}
```

It uses the `isSame` function of moment.js : https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-same/

Then bind your function :

```
<SingleDatePicker
    date={moment()}
    onDateChange={date => this.setState({ date })} 
    focused={this.state.focused} 
    onFocusChange={({ focused }) => this.setState({ focused })}
    id="your_unique_id"
    numberOfMonths={1}
    renderCalendarDay={() => availableDates.map(d => moment(d).format(d))}
    className="select-btn selectbtn-picker"
    isDayBlocked={this.isBlocked}
/>
```

Comment: What is `day` in `isBlocked = day => {}` ?

Comment: `day` is a moment.js date given by `react-dates`, the function is called for every single day that is going to be rendered in the calendar, this function expects you to return a boolean indicating if the day should be disabled.

Comment: You can see an example of it being used here, as there is no documentation for every single functions : http://airbnb.io/react-dates/?selectedKind=SDP%20-%20Day%20Props&selectedStory=with%20some%20blocked%20dates&full=0&addons=1&stories=1&panelRight=0&addonPanel=storybook%2Factions%2Factions-panel

Comment: It is blocking all the upcoming days. :-(... I need to show only the days which are avaiblable in the `availableDates` array. Rest of them need to block

Comment: Weird... Just edited my answer by putting the raw date instead of converting it into a moment object.

Comment: No it is still blocking all the upcoming days.

Comment: Suppose I have to block the days which are inside the array `availableDates`. Then What do I do?

Comment: Oh, then just do the opposite by removing the `!` right next to the `return`

Comment: No it doesn't block the dates which is inside the array. We are missing something else. And also `isBlocked` returning a function

Comment: `isBlocked` is returning the result of `some`, winch gives out a boolean : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

Comment: just a small question it works when I save inside the code. But when I click on next previous buttons it doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

The function mentioned above needs correction, but as the edit is less than 6 chars, the site is not allowing me to. So here is the correct version.

`day` is supposed to be supplied as the second parameter to moment's `isSame` function

```
isBlocked = day => {
    const availableDates = ["2019-02-01", "2019-02-04", "2019-02-05", "2019-02-06", "2019-02-07", "2019-02-11", "2019-02-12", "2019-02-13", "2019-02-14", "2019-02-15", "2019-02-19", "2019-02-20", "2019-02-21", "2019-02-22", "2019-02-23", "2019-02-25", "2019-02-26", "2019-02-27", "2019-02-28", "2019-03-01", "2019-03-04", "2019-03-05", "2019-03-06", "2019-03-07", "2019-03-08", "2019-03-09", "2019-03-11", "2019-03-12"];
    return !availableDates.some(date => day.isSame(date, 'day'));
}
```